# Yandex Map Api v2-1. Ошибка 504 при запросе points через LoadingObjectManager

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Для отображение точек на карте использую LoadingObjectManager (LOM). Периодически загрузка меток отваливается, особенно часто при первой загрузке карты. После обновления страницы метки подгружаются. Непонятно, как обрабатывать такую ошибку? И в принципе, ошибка появляется периодично,при первичной загрузке. В чем может быть причина?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужен код хоть в каком-то виде для анализа, доступ к тестовой страничке. Без этого едва ли кто-то что сможет сказать.